# Disable search highlighting after running a substitute command

Tags: vimrc

Is it possible to enable `hlsearch` when running a search (`/`) but not on `:` commands? For example, sometimes when doing a replace (on a very narrow range of text) it get distracting when I have a bunch of other lines highlighted, for example:

[image]

Here is a ten-second video of what I've done for this: https://gyazo.com/590a1927dcc2eb75d950053601dab9a7. If the answer is 'no', is there a better alternative than pressing `:noh` (or whatever mapping to it) after every search that I'm 'done with' ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following autocommands to enable hlsearch only when using the
/ and ? (search) commands:

```
" Enable highlighting all the matches in incsearch mode
" But don't enable hlsearch always
augroup vimrc-incsearch-highlight
  autocmd!
  autocmd CmdlineEnter [/\?] :set hlsearch
  autocmd CmdlineLeave [/\?] :set nohlsearch
augroup END
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way out of the box. `hlsearch` works with the search register (`:h "/`), which is used for search, substitute and the `:global` command.

---

I personally have `hlsearch` off by default and only enable it when I need it.

I have the following mapping:

```
noremap  <F8>   :set invhlsearch hlsearch?<CR>
```

The `invhlsearch` toggles `hlsearch` and the `hlsearch?` then prints the state.